# wrong owners on ext4 drive after new installation

Tags: system-installation, permissions, ext4, ownership, uid

I have installed linux from scratch on a machine that has previously linux running. On my additional "data" drive (only data, no system files) with ext4 filesystem, the file owners / groups are not correct any more. I think this is because the UID-numbers have changed with the new installation. However, in the new installation all users and groups exist that have been there in the previous installation.

Is there any nice way to "backup" all the file-owners on the old system, and "restore" them on the new system without touching the actual data?

I am aware that I could dig through the data with sudo chown and manually set the correct users for each folder - however it would be nice if there was an automatic way to do this, since the files are owned by several users.

I still have both installations (however, I want to dump the old installation once everything is running, so no dual-boot solution is needed). command line is OK and preferred by me.

Comment: Since the new installation has different UID/GIDs than the old, it would be simpler to change the UID/GIDs to match the old system, rather than changing all the files. Additionally, all your backups will still be correct too.

Comment: Thanks. When changing the UIDs to match the "data" drive, wouldn't i break the assignments on all the files that are not on the "data" drive (like home drive, and other data where the user is owner)

Comment: You said this was a new install. I assumed all the user homes were default/empty, so switching the owner name on them would be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
sudo getfacl -R /data > facl.txt
```

to save the file owners on the old system into the file `facl.txt` (replace `/data` with the actual path).

Restore the file owners stored in the file `facl.txt` with

```
sudo setfacl --restore=facl.txt
```